# problem with a function in c (linux)

Tags: c++, mysql, c, function

I'm writing a C script to generate some sitemaps for some sections of my site. I'm trying to clean it up by moving a loop into a function that I can call instead of having several large loops on top of eachother in my script.

I'm not fluent in C by ANY means, I can work my way around it but functions are pretty confusing.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    mysql_query(conn, qryListings);
    if((resultset2 = mysql_use_result(conn))) {
        write_to_sitemap(row2, resultset2);
    }

    void write_to_sitemap(MYSQL_ROW row2, MYSQL_RES* resultset2){
        while ((row2 = mysql_fetch_row(resultset2)) != NULL) {
            printf("    %s \n",row2[2]);
        }
    }
```

This is giving me the following errors:
warning: conflicting types for âwrite_to_sitemapâ
warning: previous implicit declaration of âwrite_to_sitemapâ was here

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you declared your function write_to_sitemap() in your header file?

Comment: Just a stylistic note: I avoid assignments in conditionals unless it absolutely cannot be helped or it makes the code _much_ uglier to do it another way. The first thing I think when I see one is: "was this intentional, or an accident?" You've put parenthesis around them, which is good, but it is still only slightly less confusing.

Comment: it was a copy/paste snippet from another script, I really don't know much in C so if I copy/paste something and it works, it stays as is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to (pre)declare `write_to_sitemap` before its first use:

```
void write_to_sitemap(MYSQL_ROW row2, MYSQL_RES* resultset2);
```

or move its entire definition up in your file.

Comment: how do I pre-declare a function? I prefer to have my int main at the top and the function under it.